# sed - 'extra character after the command'

Tags: sed

having trouble with a sed command.
I'm looking to find a line in a file and replace it.
In my script I've used this command without issue; (I use it to set variables)

```
sed -i '/job=empty/c\job='$job'' $sd/pingcheck-mon-$job.sh
```

The line I want to replace looks like this,

```
bash home/user/pingcheck/pingcheck-jobs/job1/pingcheck-mon-job1.sh
```

This is the command I can't get to run:

```
sed -i '/bash '$sd'/pingcheck-mon-'$job'.sh/c\jobslot=empty' $wd/pingcheck-worker.sh
```

Error I get:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: extra characters after command
```

Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246280/extra-characters-after-command-in-the-sed-command-a

(it looks like you are missing a newline after /c)

Comment: @zeppelin - I'm looking to replace the line though, not append or insert :-/

Comment: It may take some time to agree on whether a newline is missing. In the meantime, why not hard-code the variables and omit the "-i", just to simplify the problem?

Comment: your pattern itself contains `/`.. so use a different delimiter like `|`... to substitute bash variables, you need to use double quotes instead of single